# Select and load txt file to android application (Delphi-XE5)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I would like to browse SD card, select dir and file and load txt file to my Android application created by Delphi XE5.

Is any standart component or methods for this ? Like OpedFileDialog ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent for `TOpenFileDialog` on Android. It's not part of the operating system, and is not available from the Component Palette when targeting Android.

You can see this by viewing the form in the designer, and then checking the `Dialogs` tab in the Component Palette; all of the components are disabled, meaning they're not available for the targeted platform. Hovering the mouse over any of them indicates they're available for Win32, Win64, and OS X, but not iOS or Android.

You could always build your own, based on a `TForm` (or better yet, a `TPopup`, which is a better fit for the typical application flow for a mobile device), using the functionality available in `IOUtils.TPath` for retrieving directories and filenames. Once you have the filename, the functionality of loading it is simple and available in several ways - here are a few:

- Load it using `TFile.ReadAllLines` (again from `IOUtils`)
- `TStringList.LoadFromFile`
- Using `TFileStream.LoadFromFile`
- Using a `TMemo.Lines.LoadFromFile`

Comment: Android does not have a standard dialog for choosing a file, but it does have an API for creating custom dialogs, so I'm surprised that Embarcadero did not implement `TOpenDialog`/`TOpenFileDialog` to use a custom dialog/form internally.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yeah, I was too. I'm hoping that was due to the quick release of Android support in XE5 after XE4, and that it will be added at some point in an update/future version.

Answer (score -1):

Use `TStringList`, with the `TStringList.loadFromFile(file);`

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   TextFile : TStringList;
   FileName : string;
begin

try
  textFile := TStringList.Create;
  try
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}//if the operative system is Android
     FileName := Format('%smyFile.txt',[GetHomePath]);
  {$ENDIF ANDROID}

  {$IFDEF WIN32}
     FileName := Format('%smyFile.txt',[ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))]);
  {$ENDIF WIN32}

  if FileExists(FileName) then begin
     textFile.LoadFromFile(FileName); //load the file in TStringList
     showmessage(textfile.Text);//there is the text
  end
  else begin showMessage('File not exists, Create New File');

     TextFile.Text := 'There is a new File (Here the contents)';
     TextFile.SaveToFile(FileName);//create a new file from a TStringList

  end;
  finally
     textFile.Free;
  end;
except
  on E : Exception do ShowMessage('ClassError: '+e.ClassName+#13#13+'Message: '+e.Message);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: You missed the major portion of the question, which was about an OpenFileDialog for Android and using it to select a directory and allow the user to choose a file. Without doing that part first, there's no `FileName` to load wit `TStringList.LoadFromFile`

Comment: Isn't supported for the android platform

Name : TOpenDialog
Unit : FMX.Dialogs
Package : dclfmxstd190.bpl
Supported platforms:
32-bit Windows
64-bit Windows
OS X

Comment: Don't tell *me* in a comment. I know that already (see my answer, particularly the first two paragraphs). The poster asked the question; you should be telling them. :)