# How to get image path from iOS?

Tags: php, ios, delphi, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

Im working on Delphi XE5 for uploading a file on a server. Im using a php script to upload the file on the server in a directory,its working fine. the code is

Delphi code

```
Function Upload(sfilepath : string) : string;
var
  Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  Response: TStringStream;
  http: TIdHttp;
begin
  try
    http := TIDHttp.Create(nil);
    http.HandleRedirects := true;
    http.ReadTimeout := 5000;
    http.Request.ContentType:='multipart/form-data';

    Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    Response := TStringStream.Create;
    try                              
      Params.AddFile('file',sfilepath , 'image/jpg');  // 'C:\Sc.png'
      http.Post('http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/mages/php/uploadFilesToserverDirectory.php', Params, Response);
      result:=Response.DataString;
    finally
      Params.Free;
      Response.Free;
      http.Free;
    end;
  except
    on e: Exception do
    ShowMessage(e.Message);
  end;
end;
```

php code

```
 < ?php
 if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
 {
  $target = 'uploads/'. time();
  $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);
    if (!$result) {
   echo 'Cannot copy';   }
 }
```

This works fine on windows as i can use Topendialog and send the path
Params.AddFile('file',sfilepath , 'image/jpg');

but how to do this in iOS?
i want to browse the image(or any file) and get its path to send it as an argument in Function Upload(sfilepath : string) : string; ?

The samples from `\RAD Studio\12.0\Samples\MobileCodeSnippets\CameraRoll` doesnt give me the image path

```
procedure TCameraRollForm.TakePhotoFromLibraryAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
 begin
  { Assign the image retrieved from the Photo Library to the TImage component. }
  imgPhotoLibraryImage.Bitmap.Assign(Image);
 end;
```

Is there a way i can send the bitmap on the server via iOS ?

Comment: Well, your problem has nothing to do with sending the picture, nor anything to do with your server or PHP. Your problem is how to browse for pictures via iOS correct?

Comment: For file locations on various target platforms, and the functionality in `IOUtils.TPath` that locates them, I'd suggest you [start here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Standard_RTL_Path_Functions_across_the_Supported_Target_Platforms)

Comment: Also, see [this related question about TOpenDialog on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19841240/62576). I don't think iOS supports a standard open dialog either.

Comment: I've never seen any standardized file selector on iOS, other than in iOS its self. Otherwise, all other apps seem to have their own.

Comment: @psqluser I suggest you edit your question and remove all the stuff related to your server uploading and change it to ask your ultimate goal of selecting the picture to be sent.

Comment: Do you want the user to select from the Photos library?

Comment: @JerryDodge Yes, i want the path of the image

Comment: @KenWhite : `Device: This function returns an empty string as this directory is currently not supported` on the site you mentioned..so we cant have the path at all ?

Comment: @MarcusAdams : i want the user to select photos from the phone (Camera roll) and get the path of the image selected.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be what it's saying, unless you can locate a way using the OS functionality that FMX doesn't wrap. I'd suspect it's not that straightforward, or they would have done so.